# Two Conflicting jQuery Scripts, Only One Will Work

Tags: jquery

I've got a slideshow that executes when the DOM is ready.

And I've got an external script that loads content from other pages when a link is clicked in the nav.

Well, the slideshow works like a charm, but when you click on a link? Nothing.

**If I remove the slideshow script, my AJAX works like a charm, even when I'm testing locally. But when I run both scripts at the same time, my AJAX fails.**

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

   <!-- [if IE]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->

   <!--[if IE]><![endif]-->

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site-styles.css" />

   <!-- referencing latest version of jquery library -->
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

   <!-- referencing local js file -->
   <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

   <!-- referencing cross-slide plugin -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cross-slide.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <img src="img/parlorLogo.png" width="260" height="43" />
            <h4><a href="">To make a reservation, click here</a></h4>
            </header>

    <div id="contentBox">
        <div id="theContent">
            <script>
              $(function() {
                $('#contentBox').crossSlide({
                  sleep: 2,
                  fade: 1,
                  loop: 1
                }, [
                  { src: 'img/intro1.jpg' },
                  { src: 'img/intro2.jpg' },
                  { src: 'img/intro3.jpg' },
                  { src: 'img/intro4.jpg' },
                  { src: 'img/intro5.jpg' },
                  { src: 'img/intro6.jpg' },
                  { src: 'img/intro7.jpg' },
                  { src: 'img/intro8.jpg' },
                  { src: 'img/intro9.jpg' },
                  { src: 'img/intro10.jpg' },
                  { src: 'img/homeBG.jpg' },
                  { src: 'img/ticker.png' }
                ]);
              });
            </script>
        </div> <!-- theContent -->
        <noscript>Sorry, but you must enable JavaScript to view this site.</noscript>
    </div> <!-- contentBox -->

    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul id="mainNav">
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="photos.html">PHOTOS</a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="menu.html">MENU</a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="press.html">PRESS</a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="privateDining.html">PRIVATE&nbsp;DINING</a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                </h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div> <!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>
```

And the external script...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#mainNav a').click(function(){

var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #theContent';
$('#theContent').hide('fast',loadContent);

function loadContent() {
    $('#theContent').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
}
function showNewContent() {
    $('#theContent').show('fast');
}

return false;

});
});
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks much,

Adam

Comment: Are there any errors thrown in the console?

Comment: Like I said, the AJAX works fine if I take out the slideshow script. But the two together are no bueno.

Answer (score 3):

In your HTML, you have this:

```
<div id="theContent">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#contentBox').crossSlide({
```

And in your external script, you have this:

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#theContent').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
}
```

So your external script will vaporize your inlined JavaScript in your HTML when it replaces the content of `#theContent` with the `load` call.

Try moving your inlined JavaScript outside the `<div id="theContent">`.

Also, from the comments, you're not running any of this through a server. AJAX calls, such as [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load), generally don't work with the local file system to due security issues. So, if you need to test AJAX, set up a web server.

And, finally, the most likely source of your problem (which I really should have spotted right away):

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#theContent').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    //--------------------------------------------^^
}
```

The `load` function wants a *function* as the callback but you're *executing* the `showNewContent` function and leaving its return value as the callback. Your `loadContent` should look like this:

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#theContent').load(toLoad,showNewContent)
}
```

I dropped the empty string `data` argument too, you don't need it.

Comment: I moved the internal Javascript to the bottom of the page. The slideshow still works. But the navbar links still do not work.

Comment: @AdamJay: Looks okay (http://jsfiddle.net/dxp9T/), any errors? Anything in your server logs?

Comment: @AdamJay: Server logs? Or are you trying to run without a server?

Comment: I'm developing locally. No server involved yet. Should I host it on MAMP or something for the time being?

Comment: @AdamJay: Yes, AJAX doesn't work without a server. That could be the source of all your problems but moving stuff out of `#theContent` is a good idea too as that will avoid possible timing issues.

Comment: Alas, hosting it locally yields the same result. Maybe something to do with the files I'm pulling from? The about.html file for example?

Comment: @AdamJay: See my latest update, sorry, I should have spotted that right away. On the upside, you got a few potential and confusing problems sorted out for free :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code I note you are using the html5 enabling script. First check out the comments here:

http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/

> call the html5.js script AFTER you call the initial jquery.js script

I recently had some issues with a jquery script using AJAX in ie7 & ie8 only. Really odd behaviour of appending divs with the text "div" to the html body. **Removing html5 shiv solved the problem**, so there may be some sort of conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the crossSlide code inside $(document).ready.

Comment: It is already in a `document.ready`. `$(function() { });` is a short-cut for `document.ready`.